# How do I update a single value inside a nested table type in Oracle11g?

Tags: sql, oracle

My types and tables are as follows,

```
create type investments_type as object(
  company ref stocks_type,
  purchase_price number(12,2),
  date_purchased date,
  qty number
);

create type investments_table_type as table of investments_type;

create type clients as object(
  client_name varchar(50),
  address address_type,
  investments investments_table_type
);

create table clients_table of clients
NESTED TABLE investments STORE AS investments_table;
```

Now what I want to do is update the `qty` in the `investments_type` according to the `date_purchased`.

I have tried doing it like like this,

```
update clients_table
set investments = CAST(MULTISET(
select investments_type(company,purchase_price,date_purchased,qty+100)
from table(investments) i
where i.date_purchased < '01-MAR-00') as investments_table_type)
```

But this replaces all other values in the table.

How can I only update the qty value of the rows that satisfy the where condition without replacing any other rows?

**EDIT**

This is how I managed to do it.

```
update table(select c.investments
             from clients_table c) i
set i.qty = i.qty + 100
where i.date_purchased < '01-MAR-00';
```

Comment: If it's very difficult to make a trivial update, your data model has *serious* problems.  Probably not what you want to hear, but the best answer is probably "stop using object-relational technology".

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your object type to a table and update this one. It looks like this (not tested):

```
update 
    (select purchase_price, date_purchased, qty 
    from clients_table 
    natural join table(investments) 
    where date_purchased < '01-MAR-00')
set qty = qty + 100;
```

Small hint from my side: When you want to learn about Oracle Object Types, start with simpler structs, not "Object of Object of Table of Object"