# Temporal Database Update and Delete queries

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I need some help to resolve the problem that i wrote below,

```
UPDATE OYKUN_EMPLOYEE t1,table(t1.EMPMANAGER) t2 SET t2.value = 'ÖYKÜN' WHERE EMPNO=100
```

Its temporal database and I'm getting the error 'SET' keyword is missing. How can i handle this error.
EMPMANAGER is the column name which contains VT_LB, VT_UB, VALUE attributes. I'm using attribute timestamping approach

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730999/how-do-i-update-a-single-value-inside-a-nested-table-type-in-oracle11g

Comment: It updates whatever i want but i need to add new tuple according to the update. For example;   I have updated manager name let say , old manager name must be remains with its valid times. Attribute time stamping i need to do

Comment: You must elaborate more on this with some sample data and table definitions. Otherwise, it would be just a guessing game for us.